# Chrome Version 43.0.2357.124m will not play any video utilizing HTML5

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

The videos endlessly "load". I've uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome. I have the latest version. I've cleared all cache/history to the "beginning of time".  All videos utilizing Flash play fine in Chrome. ALL HTML5 videos plays in IE or in Firefox. I am on a Win 7 Pro desktop.

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.